# Does AAA+BBB+CCC+DDD=ABCD have a solution for distinct digits A,B,C,D?

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, alphametic, solvability

I was asked to solve the following sum:

> AAA
>   BBB
>   CCC
>   DDD
>   -*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*
>   ABCD

What I managed to found is that `111A + 111B + 111C + 111D = 1000A + 100B + 10C + D` which rearranged becomes:

> 889A - 11B - 101C - 110D = 0

Also that `A + B + C = 10 or 20`

> If A + B + C = 10 --> C = D + 1
>   If A + B + C = 20 --> C = D + 2

Here after trying all the combination of C and D and plugging them into the 2 equations above to solve for A and B. I managed to found that the only solution that gives integer values is (I'll masked it in case anyone wants to solve it on their own):

> 222 + 999 + 999 + 777 = 2997

My friend is insisting that 2 letters cannot be equals. Is something in my reasoning wrong? Is there another solution or this is the only solution?

Comment: A quick brute-force search only found yours and 0 as a valid solution (assuming A, B C and D are 1 digit from 0 to 9 and that we are working in base 10).

Comment: Your friend is trolling you. As already described, there is no answer for A,B,C,D all different.

Comment: Related: [ABCDE = the sum of all of its 3-letter permutations (ABC + ABD + ABE + BAC + BAD + …)](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/8890/abcde-the-sum-of-all-of-its-parts). Also necessarily involves a multiple of 111.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is:

> There is no solution with $A, B, C, D$ all different and $A \neq 0$.

Because:

> As you noted $AAA+BBB+CCC+DDD=111(A+B+C+D)$. In particular, ABCD must be a multiple of 111. Since $A \neq 0$, ABCD is more than $9 \cdot 111 = 999$ but less than $31 \cdot 111 = 3441$ since $A+B+C+D \leq 9+8+7+6 = 30$. So  ABCD equals $k \cdot 111$ for a two-digit number $k\leq 30$, so it equals $(10m+n)111 = m\cdot 1000 + (m+n) \cdot 100 + (m+n) \cdot 10 + n \cdot 1$. Because the middle two digits are not equal, we must have $m+n\geq10$ (so that it carries). If $m=1$, $n=9$, then ABCD equals 2109, so $A+B+C+D= 12\neq 10m+n=19$. If $m=2$, $n=8$, then ABCD equals 3108, so $A+B+C+D= 12\neq 10m+n=28$. If $m=2$, $n=9$, then ABCD equals 3219, so $A+B+C+D= 15\neq 10m+n=29$. Also, $m\leq2$ because $k\leq 30$ and $m=3, n=0$ is clearly not possible.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is

> **There is no solution**

Unless

> We allow letters to be equal

This includes

> With zeros and with leading zeros

I can't add a full explanation now, but brute force confirms this.

Others feel free to add your own answer with an explanation

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your friend is being a little tricky - since

> this wont work in *any* integer base using (the normal) non-negative digits

How about

> using (not normal!) negative digits?
>
>  For example in base ten with:
>  1) $A=-1,B=0,C=1,D=-9$ or
>  2) $A=2,B=-1,C=9,D=8$
>  (other integer bases greater than $3$ will also have such "solutions")
>
>  1)
>  $AAA=-100-10-1=-111$
>  $BBB=0+0+0=0$
>  $CCC=100+10+1=111$
>  $DDD=-900-90-9=-999$
>  $AAA+BBB+CCC+DDD=-999$
>  $ABCD=-1000+0+10-9=-999$
>
>  2)
>  $AAA=200+20+2=222$
>  $BBB=-100-10-1=-111$
>  $CCC=900+90+9=999$
>  $DDD=800+80+8=888$
>  $AAA+BBB+CCC+DDD=1998$
>  $ABCD=2000-100+90+8=1998$